# Get millis when using new Date().toLocaleTimeString()

Tags: javascript, node.js, date

I have this code:

```
v.d = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
```

it yields something like this:

```
20:11:40
```

So this is the time of day to the second, without milliseconds.
My question is: is there a built in call that can show just the time with milliseconds?

I am looking for something like this (to the millisecond):

```
20:11:40.124
```

Comment: *toLocaleTimeString* is implementation dependent, you can't rely on getting any particular format. You might get "8:11:40 pm", or lots of other values.

Comment: @RobG I think you should have not marked this question as a duplicate; this question here is very specific about `toLocaleTimeString` which the other Q/A has really nothing related except that both are about JS datetimes. Actually there is a living standard way to get the milliseconds formated using `(new Date).toLocaleTimeString([], { hour12: false, hour: '2-digit', minute: '2-digit', fractionalSecondDigits: 3 })` will return something like `03:40:59.077`. Too pity I can't submit an answer!

Comment: @ChristosLytras—there are already 32 answers at the duplicate for formatting time, which is what the OP wants. If you have another answer, post it there. Not specifying a language for *toLocale\** methods means the returned timestamp will be based on the host's language and may not be what you expect.

Comment: @RobG IMO javascript datetime formating must not be limited to one question and many answers; there are many APIs and libraries to do that and we should not generalize every question about datetime formating. This one here is a very specific question about how to add milliseconds using **built in** method/ways with `toLocaleTimeString` that the other Q/A does not ask, but rather focuses on general datetime formating. IMO, we should not sumup every formating related question to one question and many answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works, but I am looking for something more compact if possible:

```
 const d = new Date();
 v.d = d.toLocaleTimeString() + `.${d.getMilliseconds()}`;
```

this yields:

```
20:17:30.744
```

note that to make this work well, you need to add this part:
[Formatting milliseconds to always 3 digits for d.getMilliseconds() call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50110974/formatting-milliseconds-to-always-3-digits-for-d-getmilliseconds-call)

Comment: I think this is going to be the easiest way. Just turn put it in a function and pass the date in for convenience.

Comment: Yeah looking for something as performant as possible, but I guess this will have to do for now

Comment: You can't rely on *d.toLocaleTimeString* returning a particular format. Much better to manually format the string.

Answer (score 2):

There’s to ISOString(). But stepping back a level, with that exception there’s no standard for formatting dates in js. So you can use toISOString or build up your own string with individual date functions.

Comment: you mean `Date.prototype.toISOString()` right?

Comment: Yah. Typed from my phone.

Answer (score 2):

I did find one issue with your original solution. When I perform it it yields `hh:mm:ss PM.mil`. I assume you want `hh:mm:ss.mil` Here is that solution written as a function so you can pass the date object in and get the proper format:

```js
const d = new Date()

const getTimeWithMilliseconds = date => {
  const t = d.toLocaleTimeString();
  return `${t.substring(0,8)}.${date.getMilliseconds() + t.substring(8,11)}`;
}

console.log(getTimeWithMilliseconds(d));
```

Or if you want it in 24 hour format:

```js
const d = new Date()

const getTimeWithMilliseconds = date => {
  return `${date.toLocaleTimeString('it-US')}.${date.getMilliseconds()}`;
}

console.log(getTimeWithMilliseconds(d));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't depend on *toLocaleTimeString* returning a specific format as it's implementation dependent. It's much more reliable to build the format yourself, e.g.:

```js
function getFormattedTime(date) {
  var d = date || new Date();
  var z = n => ('0'+n).slice(-2);
  var zz = n => ('00'+n).slice(-3);
  return `${z(d.getHours())}:${z(d.getMinutes())}:${z(d.getSeconds())}.${zz(d.getMilliseconds())}`;
}

console.log(getFormattedTime());
console.log(getFormattedTime(new Date(2018,1,1)));
console.log(getFormattedTime(new Date(2018,4,30,23,51,12,89)));
```

Also see [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)